# The data format changes randomly

Tags: api, random, google-analytics, formatting

I want to create an automated report that retrieves data from Google Analytics.
Unfortunately, some data is formatted dated while most are properly formatted number.
This data comes directly from Analytics so there should not be any worries ...
Can you help me please?

Comment: How are you retrieving the data, what program do you use to display it (i.e. is the problem with the raw data or does Excel apply a wrong format), can you give an example for formats that are wrong ?

Comment: I'm retrieving the data by using google sheets with the Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on : [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on). This Add-on generate an automated spreasheet. If you want, I could give you an access to this spreadsheet to see the problem.